# How can I override the onpaste function for the editor in QuillJS?

Tags: javascript, quill

I have set up a web app that sends server requests when we focus or blur from the the root div in quill (because of the system constraints I cannot change).

However, the onpaste function in quill calls blur and focus manually, and that causes issues for my workflow.

How do I override the onpaste function?